# How to show this series converges $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1/2}\sin(n)\sin(n^2)$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series

I want to see if this series converges or not:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1/2}\sin(n)\sin(n^2).
$$
I tried comparison tests but nothing. I saw that integral criteria works but I don't know how to show that.

Thank you

Comment: Convergence would follow if sums of the form $\sum_{n=1}^M \sin(n)\sin(n^2)$ had an upper bound independent of $M$. This is certainly known for sums $\sum_{n=1}^M \sin(n)$. I'm sure it's also true for these sums, but I don't have an immediate proof.

Comment: I'm pretty sure using basic trig and quadratic identities allows us to reduce @ToddTrimble 's method to whether $\sum_{n = 1}^M \sin((n + a)^2)$ and $\sum_{n = 1}^M \cos((n + a)^2)$ are bounded. That said, I suspect that while the question may not be immediately obvious, it seems unlikely to be asked with research-level understanding.

Comment: Sounds like one of those "it's either trivial, or depends on the irrationality measure of pi being 2" questions :D

Comment: Well, indeed the sum telescopizes nicely, but the joy is immediately killed by the suspicion of homeworkness

Comment: Thank you everyone for help. I'm training for some exams and I found it. I lost like 3 hours trying to solve it. Now I got it, thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As indicated by Todd Trimble in comments, we can use the Dirichlet test; here, since $$\sin(n)\sin(n^2)=\frac12\big( \cos n(n-1)   - \cos n(n+1) \big)$$
we have a telescopic sum $$\sum_{n=1}^M \sin(n)\sin(n^2)=\frac12-\frac12  \cos M(M+1)=\sin^2\Big(\frac{M(M+1)}2\Big),$$
that does not exceed $1$ in absolute value.